# How to deal with log-intensive pods in Kubernetes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, fluentd

Hello to everyone out there,

we currently have a problem with one of our pods in an AWS EKS cluster. The pod logs pretty heavily and gets evicted regularly, because it exceeds the ephemeral-storage limit. Unluckily, we are running an old version of EKS with docker container engine, but we aim to migrate to a newer version soon. Currently, we also do not have any log rotation configured.

While thinking about a way to avoid that behavior, I came up with 2 possibilities:

1. Remove the ephemeral-storage limit currently set and use a log rotation tool (e.g. fluentd) to rotate the logs on node-level.
2. Have a sidecar container which somehow clears/rotates the logs inside the container (is it possible with logs written to stdout?)

Ideally, I´d like to have a hybrid solution which allows for having ephemeral-storage limit, if wanted, but avoids filling it up with logs. I´m wondering what happens in situation 1 after some time. Will the memory consumption increase? This seems to be a pretty standard problem, but I was not able to find a satisfying answer to this during my research. How do you usually deal with log-intensive pods in Kubernetes?

Thanks for any hints and answers in advance

Comment: K8s should be handling log output rotation for you. Are you logging to a file in ephemeral storage instead of stdout?

Comment: No, the application logs to stdout. Is this also the case for docker container engine@eks? And does that mean that case 1 would be the way to go?

Comment: So as per my understanding: If I do not specify ephemeral-storage limit, the limit is the available storage attached to the node. So logging extensively will eat up my storage after a certain amount of time. Is that correct? If yes, what can I do about it? Will this be handled y Kubernetes then?

Comment: From what I understand, vanilla K8S does not manage log sizes for you, but EKS does. I see old docks indicating that EKS does the log limit and rotation via `docker`, but I assume an equivalent exists in newer version of EKS with CRI-O. For the most part, you can just not worry about it on EKS as long as it's written to stdout and not a local file

Comment: @EllisTheEllice did you find the answer to your question? We want to manage log rotation for our EKS cluster  having a docker runtime but kubelet parameters are not taking effect.

Comment: In our case, there was a problem with the underlying AMI: It was a hardened AMI that we got from the security team, but it behaved a bit weirdly. After many tests, we were able to show that the behavior was as described by @jordanm for a standard AMI. So the team solved this on AMI basis and we did not need to worry about this problem anymore (due to auto-rotation).

Comment: @JimitRaithatha FYI the latest two version of EKS no longer support docker runtime and the versions that do support it will lose support in about 1yr.